# SQL truncate table where table name is defined in function argument or variable

Tags: python, pymysql

I'm trying to pass variable or function argument to the execute method

```
import pymysql

tablename = 'test_table'

con = pymysql.connect(**...)
with con.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE %s", tablename)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test_table'' at line 1")
```

Expecting to see no errors and the test_table empty of rows.

Answer (score 1):

SO is slacking lately...

I did this instead and it worked:

```
import pymysql

tablename = 'test_table'

con = pymysql.connect(**...)
with con.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE %s" % tablename)
con.commit()
con.close()

print('Done')
```